# How can I download xlsx file in ReactJs with the api response which is some binary stream of xlsx file

Tags: reactjs, xlsx, filestream

How do i download the xlsx file which is the binary string response received from the API GET call:

[image: binary_string]

with the provided headers and response structure?

[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InbV5.png)

I'm currently using the following code for the GET request:

```
const response = await ApiUtils.get('users?pageSize=0&download=true')
```

In this code, the GET request is handled by the get function, which includes a timeout parameter. When I use the "Send and Download" feature in Postman, the resulting xlsx file is downloadable and readable.

However, when I attempt to implement this in my frontend application, I encounter the following issues as illustrated in the images:

[image: issue_while_opeing]
[image: post_fixing_corrupt_file]

The code which I used to implement the download functionality is:

```
const handleDownload = () => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([response.data], {
        type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
      })
    );
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.innerText = 'Open the array URL';
    link.setAttribute('download', 'myExcel.xlsx');
    link.click();
  };
```

I was trying to replicate something which Postman was doing since it was able to download the file seamlessly in readable format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the handleDownload function, blob is created considering the data in the response is arraybuffer
[blog reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#instance_methods)

`Blob.prototype.arrayBuffer() Returns a promise that resolves with an ArrayBuffer containing the entire contents of the Blob as binary data.`

So when the response from the API is of type different from that of required type i.e. The ArrayBuffer object which is used to represent a generic raw binary data buffer.
[blog reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer)

**Solution**

To fix the problem here, reading the responseType to the get call will solve the issue as follows:

```
get = async (url, options = {}) => {
const { requestTimeout = this.defaultTimeout, responseType } = options;
try {

  const response = await this.request.get(url, {
    timeout: requestTimeout,
    responseType,
  });
  return response;
```

and passing the response type where the response needs to converted to be downloaded as xlsx file in readable fromat/ or any response which is binary raw stream not encoded while performing the download

```
const response = await ApiUtils.get('users?pageSize=0&download=true', {
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
});
```